# injecting jQuery, Colorbox, & custom code into a page via a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, bookmarklet

I've been inspired by the [Instapaper bookmarklets](http://www.instapaper.com/extras) that allow a page to be added to Instapaper without a separate pop-up window and without requiring a full page reload. I'd like to combine that idea with a [Delicious bookmarklet](http://www.delicious.com/help/bookmarklets) for bookmarking pages.

The [jQuery Colorbox plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) supports loading iframe content into colobox pop-ups, so it seemed like a good place to start. I pieced together several bookmarklets to get the code below, which seemed off to a good start, until I added the "[$.fn.colorbox](http://biostall.com/open-jquery-colorbox-onload)..." line. I can't seem to get a Colorbox to open. I even tried simplifying it to just open the Google hopepage, but no luck there either:

```
javascript:
function iprl5(){
  var d=document,z=d.createElement('scr'+'ipt'),y=d.createElement('scr'+'ipt'),x=d.createElement('scr'+'ipt'),b=d.body,l=d.location,t=d.selection?(d.selection.type!='None'?d.selection.createRange().text:''):(d.getSelection?d.getSelection():'');
  try{
    if(!b)
      throw(0);
    d.title='(Saving...)%20'+d.title;
    x.setAttribute('src','http://cachedcommons.org/cache/jquery/1.4.2/javascripts/jquery.js');
    y.setAttribute('src','http://cachedcommons.org/cache/jquery-colorbox/1.3.9/javascripts/jquery-colorbox.js');
    b.appendChild(x);
    b.appendChild(y);
    $.fn.colorbox({href:'http://www.delicious.com/save?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'&v=5&',open:true,iframe:true});
  }
  catch(e){
    alert('Please%20wait%20until%20the%20page%20has%20loaded.');
  }
}
iprl5();
void(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are loaded in a separate thread. You need to wait until the script is loaded before you use it. Usually something like this:

```
var checkIfLoaded = function(){
    if($.fn.colorbox){
        // continue your processing
    }else{
        window.setTimeout(200, checkIfLoaded);
    }
}
checkIfLoaded();
```